# Special collections of normal subgroups.

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $N=\{N_1,..., N_n\}$ be a list of nontrivial normal subgroups of $G$ having the following property: For every irreducible representation $\rho$ of $G$ there is some index $j$ such that $\rho$ restricted to $N_j$ is trivial.

**Question:** Give an example of group $G$ and a collection of nontrivial normal subgroups $N$ of $G$ satisfying the above.

Comment: $Z/2+Z/2$ and all its proper subgroups.

Comment: I believe $Z/p+Z/p$, $p$ prime, and all proper subgroups will do. I'm interested to find non-abelian examples.

Comment: Any group wtih non-cyclic center will do.  

Comment: Ehehe, it happens! Btw, you might be interested in this thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29813/do-semisimple-algebraic-groups-always-have-faithful-irreducible-representations
It mentions connected groups, but probably the answers can be, at least partially, adapted. Btw, why do you need such examples? This might guide better the kind of replies you get.

Comment: Yes yes of course damiano you are right. I have removed my erroneous comment. Thank you!

However I don't know if I understand clearly why having a non-cyclic center implies normal subgroups with the property mentioned in my original question. 

Such a collection of normal subgroups will provide a covering of the fusion category $Rep(G)$ by fusion (thus braided fusion) subcategories. Really I just need some examples to make an article I'm writing more readable and fun! 

Comment: You lose nothing in always choosing every non-trivial normal subgroup in your list. In particular, every non-trivial subgroup of the center appears in your list. Since the whole representation $V$ is irreducible, every element of the center acts as a scalar (by Schur's Lemma). Thus $V$ restricted to the center, has image contained in the center of $GL(V)$, i.e., in $\mathbb{C}^*$. But the finite subgroups of $\mathbb{C}^*$ are cyclic, and hence if the center is not cyclic, it cannot embed under $V$. In particular, the kernel of $V$ contains a non-trivial subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Steve and damiano would you please repost your answers appropriately so I can check the checkmark giving you your due?

Answer (score 2):

The subgroup generated by the permutations  (123), (456) and (23)(56) in $S_6$ has no faithful irreducible representation.